# Why don't 'breaking' ESLint errors show up on the browser?

Tags: next.js, eslint

I am running a Next.js (v14) app and was wondering why ESLint errors don't show up on the browser anymore during dev?

I have a bunch of ESLint rules but they don't seem to show up on the browser screen like they do for CRA when there are linting errors.

I am a fan of the app "breaking" if there were any linting errors I missed, but it seems like that functionality isn't there anymore!

I've [asked](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/59718) it on the Next.js discussion forum on GitHub, but thought I'd post it here as well.

Something like this. This is a CRA app:

[image: Something like this]

Comment: As an aside, calling a declared but unused variable an "error" is a pretty big stretch. Unless you're writing code for embedded software where every byte matters, it's probably not even worth _caring_ about, let alone "fixing". Some environments also sometimes just plain get that warning _wrong_ (e.g. a variable declared outside a scoped statement which is then populated in said statement).

Answer (score -2):

These are typing errors which will not break the Application.

These are warnings which can be elevated to errors based on the quality metrics of the project.

Comment: I know they don't break the app in the normal sense, hence why I put the 'break' in quotes.

> These are warnings which can be elevated to errors based on the quality metrics of the project.

What does this even mean? I know they are warning and not JS errors! That wasn't the question. My question was related to why these eslint 'warnings' or ' eslint errors' don't show up on the browser.